# Spring Security @PreAuthorize annotation with AuthenticationSuccessEvent

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have basic authentication and i want to log/do something on succesfull log in but AuthenticationSuccessEvent is firing up even if that ROLE dont have permission i need to access that HTTP method. How can i log/do something ONLY if i can access that HTTP method with permission.

```
@Component("authorization")
public class AuthorizationUtils {

    public boolean hasPermission(final String permission) {
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserDetails().getAuthorities();
        return authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission));
    }

    public static UserDetails getUserDetails() {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null && authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
            return (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

```
public class AuthenticationEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

  @Autowired
  private HttpServletRequest request;

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {

    String username = ((UserAccountDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUsername();

    log.trace("Account with username : {} successfully log in!", username);

    System.out.println(request.getHeader("Authorization"));
  }
```

```
  @GetMapping("/permission")
  @PreAuthorize("@authorization.hasPermission('edit.helloworld123')")
  public String editHelloWorld(){
    return "Welcome to permission edit.helloWorld!";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorization is not the same as Authentication .Authentication is about whether an user can login successfully or not.  Authorization is about if the login user have enough permission to execute a method. So even an user is successfully login (i.e `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` happens) , if he does not have enough permission to execute a method, the method still fail to execute.

What you are really want is to detect the authorization success event , but you are now detecting the authentication success event , which are totally different things.

To enable [spring-security](/questions/tagged/spring-security) to publish the authorization success event after an user who has enough permission execute a protected method successfully , you have to enable `setPublishAuthorizationSuccess` of the `MethodInterceptor`.

From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#globalmethodsecurityconfiguration) to override the default settings related to method security, you can extend `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` :

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    public MethodInterceptor methodSecurityInterceptor(MethodSecurityMetadataSource methodSecurityMetadataSource) {
        MethodInterceptor result = super.methodSecurityInterceptor(methodSecurityMetadataSource);
        ((MethodSecurityInterceptor) result).setPublishAuthorizationSuccess(true);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And `AuthorizedEvent` will be published after the user has enough permission to execute a protected method .So create a `ApplicationListener` to listen and handle it :

```java
@Component
public class MyEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthorizedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthorizedEvent event) {
        //Handle the AuthorizedEvent event here......
    }
}
```